# Vary CPPPATH based on file compiled

Tags: scons

I have some .c files that will compile to .o files. These .c files include a third party .h file.  I would like to only include the third party folder as an include location for only the files that need it.

Here are pseudo code of what I am looking to do:

```
gcc -o one.o -Imypath/include one.c
gcc -o two.o -Imypath/include two.c
gcc -o thirdpartyinterface.o -Imypath/include -Ithirdpartypath/include thirdparty.c
gcc -o theexe one.o two.o thirdpartyinterface.o
```

Note that I only want the thirdpartypath included for my thirdpartyinterface code.

The problem I am facing is that scons seems to like to use one CPPPATH for all things compiled with the one `env`.

Upon reflection I think I could build my thirdpartyinterface as a .a if that would help.

Comment: You can clone the default environment and set different `CPPPATH` for each clone. Then use the appropriate environment for files, based on whenever they are third-party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include keyword arguments to do temporary overrides when calling a builder. Those are active only for the specific build and don't change the active environment. For example:

```py
obj = Object('hello.c', CCFLAGS='-MD -MF hello.d', CPPPATH='.')
```